# Vuforia unity uwp Hololens .net 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, vuforia, hololens, .net-4.6

I have been using the Vuforia API in Unity with ILCPP in 3.5, but now i need to use .NET and version 4.x

I'm using Unity 2018.1.2. I already changed the .xml configuration files from . to , because of some errors in the compiler, as it explain in this post https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/vuforia-api/vuforia-working-net-46

But when i use it in Hololens it crashes when it recognize the image.

Looks like it's messing two files when i compile it.

[Compile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROSqC.png)

Best regards, Rafael Pereira.